# mindtouch installation

Tags: mindtouch

Can mindtouch be installed on IIS6.0, just wanted to make sure before i upgrade my OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install MindTouch on Windows with IIS6 using the MindTouch MSI which can be downloaded from http://www.mindtouch.com/Download

Corey Ganser
Customer Support
MindTouch